# Sharepoint: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am trying to import a logo of a web and its subsite in sharepoint 2013.

When I try to load the file for subsite then exception occur.

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Here is my code

```
if (siteLogo != null)
{
   File = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(siteLogo);
   Data = File.OpenBinaryStream();
   customContext.Context.Load(File);
   customContext.Context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

First Time it works fine. But when it loads for subsite it generate exception.

I tried alot to solve this but unable to find the solution. Please help.

This is complete file

```
public Branding(SharePointClientContext customContext, string siteLogo, string alternateCss, ListItemCollection ltItemCollection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web)
    {
        if (ltItemCollection != null)
        {
            ListItem item = ltItemCollection.Where(a => a.DisplayName == "Current").FirstOrDefault();
            if (item.FieldValuesAsText != null && item.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues["ThemeUrl"] != null && item.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues["ThemeUrl"] != "")
            {
                string themeUrl = item.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues["ThemeUrl"].Split(',')[1];
                string themeFileName = themeUrl.Substring(themeUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).ToLower();
                ListItem selectedTheme = ltItemCollection.Where(a =>
                                                        a.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues["ThemeUrl"].Split(',')[1].Substring(a.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues["ThemeUrl"].Split(',')[1].LastIndexOf('/') + 1) == themeFileName
                                                        && a.DisplayName != "Current").FirstOrDefault();
                this.Theme = selectedTheme.DisplayName;

            }
        }

        if (siteLogo != null)
        {
            File = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(siteLogo);
            Data = File.OpenBinaryStream();
            customContext.Context.Load(File);
            customContext.Context.ExecuteQuery();
            File = null;
        }

        if (alternateCss != null && alternateCss != "")
        {
            CssFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(web.SiteLogoUrl);
            CssData = CssFile.OpenBinaryStream();
            web.Context.Load(CssFile);
            web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
            CssFile = null;
        }
    }
```

And calling this in following way.

```
SharePointConstants.branding.Add(new Branding(customContext, siteLogo, AlternateCss, ltItemCollection, web));
```

Comment: Good Question ! Where Are You Getting Values

Comment: I am doing this code in Constructor of a class.

Comment: I can show you other files too.

Comment: Can you figure out the problem?